# Building an Interactive Map using C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, mapping, virtual, interactive

I have a **small simple project** on building a clickable interactive map of our school.

The challenge is to create a clickable parcel of map and add an animation 
directing the user from point A to B using the given roads/hallways on the map. Moreover, I would like to create a database that allows the user to view the information for that specific parcel of map when clicked.

I'm using C# to program this one. My application is Visual Studio 2010

Example Links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbinL2pg5Hs
- http://www.wayfinderkiosk.com/

QUESTIONS:

1. What are the processes(step-by-step) on creating this project?
2. What applications should I need for programming, database, animating, drawing etc.?

Comment: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/ , http://gmapdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Will you also need a database which can track all pupils and all teachers? Seriuosly, it sounds like a lot of fun, but __not__ exactly very _small and simple_. Take a step back and __WRITE DOWN__ all your requirements. Let me repeat: Do try to __WRITE DOWN ALL__ your requirements!!

Comment: Good point. I will definitely get back on this and write down all the requirements. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Decide on the platform you will be using: WinForms, WPF, WinRT, ASP... If your project description includes the platform then you know; if not keep the question in mind!
- Get your resources. Get the map and a list of all the places you will work with. Also all the extras like the descriptions and photos etc. Get this chore out of the way now. It'll help you to get a feeling for the amount of things you will put into the project.
- Know your clients. An older kiosk system runs only only a few kiosks. Today maybe you need/want to have it run on the web and on portable devices. This will make a difference in not just for screen sizes but also in the number of possible routes..
- Define user input controls. Keyboard? Mouse? Touch? Which buttons? You need a complete list!
- Define the user interactions. Completely. Try to make tables of states the system can go through.
- Try to decide on how the path finding should work. This anything but trivial, as soon as you want to include more than a few points.. You can have a set of ready made paths or try to find them or build them from a list of partial paths. This may well be the toughest part of it. Some folks believe in 'Hardest First' other in  'Hardest Last'. I believe that the first thing is to understand the hard parts well enough to get a feeling for them and to decide then.

Well that is really just a start, off the top of my head.

Good luck and have fun!!

Comment: I'm using WinForms for this project since I've just started learning it. I will definitely create a new one using ASP.NET to transfer it on the web as you've suggested.

Thank you for the guide. It was very helpful.